# How to use _logger.LogInformation/error with security (development security)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, logging

I use in my code `_logger.LogInformation($"...")` to save sensitive data, but I would know how I use this within development security because OWASP says to protect sensitive data. Do I need to record this with cryptography?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: The best way to protect sensitive data is not to record it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a server error, you can freely record the error as long as it is recorded on the server. Do not output the error back to the client - the end user should have as little information as possible on what happened (unless it's a validation issue).

For example: If the user enters a string of letters into the Telephone field. Feel free to return the error

> Please enter a valid phone number

If they click a button and the server throws an exception, log the error to your server but only inform the client that

> An error occurred. Please try again later

When it comes to logging data relating to personal information (things that you should keep secure), it's better to log a reference.

A bad log would be

> The user John Doe (john.doe@email.com) changed their profile picture.

A good log would be something like

> User with the userId (21) changed their profile picture on 2019-06-28 at 11:21:46

This way if you ever need to look at the logs to see what the system did, you can see exactly what the system was doing without needing to reveal any personal data. If there was a problem with a system, you could use the reference (such as searching for the User with the ID of 21) to find the relevant information relating to that account. A good rule is "If it doesn't need to be there, don't store it".

I'm not the best at writing but I hope this helps you better understand how to log without storing PII / sensitive data.